# gscam - "illegal operation"

Tags: gscam, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get a camera working on a "roboard" (i386) which is running Ubuntu 10.04 with a full ROS diamondback install.

gscam is falling down at the following line (in http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/gscam/src/gscam.cpp ), and only returning illegal operation.

```
image_transport::CameraPublisher pub = it.advertiseCamera("gscam/image_raw", 1);
```

This setup works on a laptop running the same code, has anyone else had this problem or know a solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10456/gscam---%22illegal-operation%22/) by [alexsleat](https://answers.ros.org/users/775/alexsleat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-09-08**:
Did you compile all of ROS or did you install from .debs?

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-09-02**:
We're going to need more details to debug this; corefiles, version numbers, etc. Also, does it work in (recently-released!) electric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even if it is i386, you can get an illegal operation if some extensions are not supported.

Things like SSE might be standard on most current machines and thus are compiled in by default. On a raw i386 you would get that error. The solution would be to recompile without the flags.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1